# How to get sub-string between two repetitive keywords in Python

Tags: python, regex

Denote a string:

```
 string = 'Other unwanted text here and start here: This is the first sentence.\nIt is the second one.\nNow, this is the third one.\nThis is not I want.\n'
```

I want to extract the first three sentence, that is,

```
This is the first sentence.\nIt is the second one.\nNow, this is the third one.
```

Apparently, the following regular expression does not work:

```
re.search('(?<=This)(.*?)(?=\n)', string)
```

What is the correct expression for extracting text between `This` and the third `\n`?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you meant to have `\nNow ...` instead of `\Now`. I also think you could split on `\n` to make it simpler (and join back the first 3 elements of the split using `\n`)

Comment: Thank you, Jerry. But I want to know how to solve it using regex.

Comment: Do you have any reasons why you want to do that? Why you want to use a tool that you don't know how to use, especially when there are more efficient solutions to solve that particular problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex for capturing three sentences starting with `This` text,

```
This(?:[^\n]*\n){3}
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hjuBKs/5)**

**Edit:**

Python code,

```
import re

s = 'Other unwanted text here and start here: This is the first sentence.\nIt is the second one.\nNow, this is the third one.\nThis is not I want.\n'

m = re.search(r'This(?:[^\n]*\n){3}',s)
if (m):
 print(m.group())
```

Prints,

```
This is the first sentence.
It is the second one.
Now, this is the third one.
```

Comment: How to extract text between `This` and the `third \n`?

Comment: I tried `re.search('(?<=This)((?:[^\n]*\n){3})', string)` but it returns `None`.

Comment: I also created a demo: https://repl.it/repls/OvercookedAdventurousDownload. Please check.

Comment: Thank you very much, Pushpesh. But how to include `This` in the result?

Comment: @Chan: For including `This` itself too in the match, change positive look behind to literal `This` and use this regex `This(?:[^\n]*\n){3}`. [Check your modified demo](https://repl.it/repls/IckySuperficialPostgres)

Comment: Glad I could help you @Chan :)

Answer (score 0):

Jerry's right, regex isn't the right tool for the job and there are much easier and more efficient ways of tackling the problem;

```
this = 'This is the first sentence.\nIt is the second one.\nNow, this is the third one.\nThis is not I want.\n'

print('\n'.join(this.split('\n', 3)[:-1]))
```

OUTPUT:

```
This is the first sentence.

It is the second one.

Now, this is the third one.
```

If you just want to practice using regex, following a tutorial would be much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
import re

string = 'Other unwanted text here and start here: This is the first sentence.\nIt is the second one.\nNow, this is the third one.\nThis is not I want.\n'
extracted_text = re.search(r'This(.*?\n.*?\n.*?)\n', string).group(1)
print(extracted_text)
```

Giving you:

```
 is the first sentence.
It is the second one.
Now, this is the third one.
```

This assumes there was a missing `n` before `Now`. If you wish to keep `This` then you can move it inside the `(`

Comment: How to extract text between `This` and the `third \n`?

Comment: `.match()` will return a match object, and then `.group()` will give you the matched text.

Comment: Sorry for unclear question. Please see the modified question. I want the text between `This` and the `third \n` and `This` is the first word of the sentence.

Comment: I tried  your suggestions but failed. Please see  https://repl.it/@Chan2019/OvercookedAdventurousDownload

Comment: It wasn't clear if you actually wanted `\n` literally or as a newline. I have updated the solution.

Answer (score 0):

`(?s)(This.*?)(?=\nThis)`

Make the `.` include newline with `(?s)`, look for a sequence starting with `This` and followed by `\nThis`.

Don't forget that `__repr__` of the search result doesn't print the whole matched string, so you'll need to

```py
print(re.search('(?s)(This.*?)(?=\nThis)', string)[0])
```

Comment: My output for `Other unwanted text here and start here: This is the first sentence.\nIt is the second one.\Now, this is the third one.\nThis is not I want.\n`:

`This is the first sentence.\nIt is the second one.\nNow, this is the third one.`
Is this not what you want?

Comment: I tried `print(re.search('(?s)(This.*?)(?=\nThis)', string)[0])` and I got `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`.

Comment: May be caused by the fact that you assign a string like this `string = r'blah'` and not like this `string = 'blah'` First one is for regex strings. You need a regular one.